# Python Github pdoc - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named mainFile

Tags: python, github-actions, pdoc

I have two files: `mainFile.py` and `test_mainFile.py`. I am trying to generate a documentation using pdoc which works well in a command line, but when I try to do the same thing using GitHub Actions, it fails to find the file.

```
Run if [ -f __init__.py ]
  if [ -f __init__.py ]
  then
    pdoc -o docs/ `pwd`
  else
    pdoc -o docs/ `ls --hide=*.md --hide=*.txt --hide=__pycache__`
  fi
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pdoc/extract.py", line 218, in load_module
    return importlib.import_module(module)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/runner/work/AP1VS-final-project/AP1VS-final-project/project/test_mainFile.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mainFile import minMax
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainFile'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/bin/pdoc", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pdoc/__main__.py", line 185, in cli
    pdoc.pdoc(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pdoc/__init__.py", line 493, in pdoc
    all_modules[module_name] = doc.Module.from_name(module_name)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pdoc/doc.py", line 392, in from_name
    return cls(extract.load_module(name))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 81, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.0/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pdoc/extract.py", line 220, in load_module
    raise RuntimeError(f"Error importing {module}") from e
RuntimeError: Error importing project.test_mainFile
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My test_mainFile.py where I import mainFile.py looks like this:

```
"""Tests for main.py."""
import pytest
import builtins
from mainFile import minMax
from mainFile import bubbleSort
from mainFile import insertionSort
from mainFile import quickSort
from mainFile import documentInput
from mainFile import randomNumbers
from mainFile import handleInputNumbers
from mainFile import sort


def test_minMax():
...
```

When I try to do `import mainFile` directly, one of my GitHub actions then fails to find the mainfile.py step earlier while running unit tests. Everything seems to work fine on my local machine or at other computers, I just cannot find a way to make it pass through GitHub Action. Both files are in the same directory.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please share your GH Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm slow. I just put the scripts in the root directory that solved it. Wrong path